# Unhide Checkout Login form for unlogged users in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, logging, woocommerce, checkout

When a customer is not logged in, I want the Woocommerce login form to not be initially hidden on the checkout page. I would also like the create an account? Radio to be ticked like the subscribe button is by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following hooked function will enable the login form by default for unlogged users

```
// Enable the login form by default for unlogged users
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'force_checkout_login_for_unlogged_customers', 4 );
function force_checkout_login_for_unlogged_customers() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_checkout_login_form', 20 );
    }
}

function custom_checkout_login_form() {
    wc_get_template( 'global/form-login.php', array(
        'message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
        'hidden'   => false,
    ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]