# Remove login form toggle in woocommerc checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to make the login form in checkout page visible without the toggle
here is what form-login.php looks like

```
<div class="woocommerce-form-login-toggle">
    <?php wc_print_notice( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', esc_html__( 'Returning customer?', 'woocommerce' ) ) . ' <a href="#" class="showlogin">' . esc_html__( 'Click here to login', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>', 'notice' ); ?>
</div>
```

I need to remove that toggle and make the login form always visible
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here
[Unhide Checkout Login form for unlogged users in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132754/unhide-checkout-login-form-for-unlogged-)

```
users-in-woocommerce
// Enable the login form by default for unlogged users
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'force_checkout_login_for_unlogged_customers', 4 );
function force_checkout_login_for_unlogged_customers() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_checkout_login_form', 20 );
    }
}

function custom_checkout_login_form() {
    wc_get_template( 'global/form-login.php', array(
        'message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
        'hidden'   => false,
    ) );
}
```